# Given a Characteristic Polynomial of a Matrix...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

This question contains three parts. I have already answered the first two. The last part is confusing me.

Suppose $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = (x - 1)(x + 2)^2(x - 3)$.

Part (a): Show that $A$ is invertible. Find the characteristic polynomial of $A^{-1}$.

We have that the roots of a characteristic polynomial are the eigenvalues of $A$. That is, $\lambda = -2, -2, 1, 3$ are our eigenvalues. The determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix is the product of its eigenvalues. Hence, det$A = 12$. An $n \times n$ matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero. Therefore, $A$ is invertible.

Since none of the eigenvalues are zero, we have that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. Then, the characteristic polynomial for $A^{-1}$ is $q(x) = (x - 1)(x + 1/2)^2(x - 1/3)$.

Part (b): Find the determinant and trace of $A$ and $A^{-1}$.

This is easy since the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix is the product of its eigenvalues and the trace of an $n \times n$ matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Part (c): Express $A^{-1}$ as a polynomial in $A$. Explain your answer.

Not really sure what part (c) is getting at.

Comment: For the part $a$, you did not address the issue of multiplicities... I suggest instead to note that $\det(xI-A)=\det(A)\det(xA^{-1}-I)=\det(A)*(-1/x)^4\det(x^{-1}I-A)$, which does give your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we have $(A-1)(A+2)^2(A-3)=0$, that is, 
$A^4-9A^2-4A+12I=0$. 
Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$, and be amazed!

Comment: suggest you type in the $I$ for $12 I$  I see, you also wrote the factored version without any $I$

Comment: You are right, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Much appreciated. Is there an approach that does not use Cayley-Hamilton? Or is this the "obvious" way to go about this problem?

Comment: Not sure about obvious, but certainly the simplest.

Comment: Once you see that the characteristic polynomial has a nonzero constant term (nonzero coefficient of $I$), this probably becomes the "obvious" way, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for part (c): Cayley-Hamilton. Then multiply by $A^{-1}$ and solve for the inverse.

Comment: What tells you to use Cayley-Hamilton? Just the fact that it gives us a polynomial for $A$, and since $A$ is invertible, we should then be able to find a polynomial $A^{-1}$ in terms of $A$?